# The uniqueness and existence theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given, that the function
$$y(x) = \sin x+\cos x-e^x$$
is a solution of an order-2-linear ordinary differential equation (ODE) with continuous coefficients in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. Prove that the order-2-linear ODE is
non-homogeneous.

My suggestion for a proof:
Note that the zero function is a solution for the given ODE. Together with $y(x) = \sin x+\cos x-e^x$ also satisfying $y(0)=0$, this will give two solutions for the given ODE contradicting the existence and uniqueness theorem.

Remark: I can also show that $y'(0) = 0 $ since $y'(x)=\cos x-\sin x-e^x$. Also $y''(x)=-\sin x-\cos x-e^x$. However, I don't see how this is needed. I do feel that my proof is a bit "too easy". But I don't see what I am missing.
Would be happy for an opinion from people from the differential-equations field.
Thanks!

Comment: For uniqueness of solution of a second order ODE you need two initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to geetha290km I got it. Uniqueness and existence theorem of order 2 ODE applies only with two initial conditions. So the proof is:

Note that the zero function is a solution for the given ODE. Together with $y(x) = \sin x+\cos x-e^x$ and $y'(x)=\cos x-\sin x-e^x$, also satisfying the two initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$. This will give two solutions for the given ODE contradicting the existence and uniqueness theorem.

Thanks!